# How can we rewrite the following equation in terms of $\theta$? $\cos(\theta) = A\cdot\cos(D\cdot\theta) + B$ where $A,B,D\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have this equation:
$$\cos(\theta) = A\cdot\cos(D\cdot\theta) + B$$
where $A,B,D\in\mathbb{R}$

I tried rewriting $A$ and $B$ in trigonometric terms to get the equation into an expanded form of $\sin(M\pm N)$ or $\cos(M\pm N)$ but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide that this is an equation and that $B\cdots$ (fill the dots, use series to write that
$$\cos(\theta)- A\,\cos(D\,\theta) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(1-A D^{2 n})}{(2 n)!}\theta^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \,\theta^{2n}$$

Now, use [power series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) and write, as an *approximation* for the first root
$$\theta=\frac{\sqrt{B-a_0}}{\sqrt{a_1}}\left( 1--\frac{a_2 (B-a_0)}{2 a_1^2}+O\left((B-a_0)^2\right)\right)$$ You can have as many terms as you wish using  the explicit formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ term given by Morse and Feshbach.

Trying for $A=\pi$, $D=e$, $B=\frac 3 2$
$$\theta \sim\frac{\sqrt{1+2 \pi } \left(23+\pi  \left(-2-48 e^2+e^4 (1+26
   \pi )\right)\right)}{24 \left(e^2 \pi -1\right)^{5/2}}=0.632654$$ while the "exact" solution, as given by Newton method, is $0.661868$.

Using one more terms, that is to say to $O\left((B-a_0)^3\right)$, for the same example, we should obtain $0.649822$ and so forthe for better and better.

Answer (score 0):

A non-answer, but perhaps of some use, and too long for a comment:

The only path I can see to go down is for the case where $D$ is an integer, $n$, and then to write
$$
\cos x = \frac12(e^{ix} - e^{-ix}) \\
\cos nx = \frac12(e^{inx} - e^{-inx})$$
and letting $u = e^{ix}, v = e^{-ix}$ your equation becomes
\begin{align}
u-v &= A(u^n - v^n) + 2B\\
2B &= u-v - A(u-v)(u^0v^{n-1} + u^1 v^{n-2} + \ldots + u^{n-1}v^0) &\text{ this is where $n$ being an integer is used}\\ 
2B &= (u-v) \left(1 - A(u^0v^{n-1} + u^1 v^{n-2} + \ldots + u^{n-1}v^0)\right) \\
\end{align}
but to be honest, I don't see that going anywhere, even when you realize that $v = 1/u$.

Comment: You're right...I saw it in my head as $B\theta$ for some reason, so that we were setting equal a sinusoidal wave and a sloping sinusoidal wave...and in THAT case there is only a finite set of solutions. I'll edit.